# Information of a stream of bits

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

Here is my problem. I have to compute the amount of information that is possible to encode in a string of bits. This string of bits represent a stream.
Let us call such stream as $X_1,X_2,X_3,...,X_n$. Important: this succession of Random variable is not a Markov Process, but a process with memory!!
I suppose that the right measure would be based on the information entropy of the collection of random variables:
$H(X_1,X_2,X_3,...,X_n)=\sum_i H(X_i|X_{i-1},...,X_1)$

Am I right?

However I have more doubts:

- If $n \to \infty$ then a better measure would be the entropy rate, isn't it?.
- What is meaning of $H(X_n)$, i.e. the entropy of only the last random variable?
- In term of information theory, what is the meaning of $H(X_1, X_n)$ or $H(X_1| X_n)$ ?

A point is that I can compute both $H(X_1, X_n)$ and $H(X_1| X_n)$ for my process, but the computation of $H(X_1,X_2,X_3,...,X_n)$ remains very hard, as the process is non markovian.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this is better suited to cs.stackexchange.

Comment: your question is still a bit vague (to me). Could you please try to give more details?

Comment: @RanG. Sure. I have some problem with the intepretation of the shannon entropies $H(X_n)$, $H(X_1,X_n)$ , $H(X_1|X_n)$ and  $H(X_1,...,X_n)$ in term of information encoded in a sequence $X_n$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for a concrete value of $n$, $H(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ would be a good measure.

If $n \to \infty$ and you happen to know that the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} H(X_1,\dots,X_n)/n$ exists, then yes, the entropy rate would be a good measure.

I don't understand what your other questions are asking.  What is the meaning of $H(X_n)$?  It is the entropy of $X_n$.  Giving any more concrete answer will depend upon the specific process that is used to generate $X_n$.  Unless there is something specific about your situation, it is  unlikely that there is any natural meaning to assign to $H(X_1,X_n)$ or $H(X_1|X_n)$.